# Flexbox sticky footer in ASP.net masterpage

Tags: html, css, flexbox, footer

I am trying to make my footer stick to the bottom of the page, no matter how much content i have. 
I wanna do this using flexbox.

I am using masterpages in ASP.net (Microsoft Visual Studio) but it just doesn't work.

I made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkrher/8eep942d/1/) with my code.

```
html {
    height: 100vh;
} 

.alignCenter {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.site {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.siteContent {
    flex: 1;   
}
```

I tried both % and vh in the html CSS.

I also tried in regular HTML and CSS and i can make it work there shown in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkrher/7w5vk0fm/).

So why doesn't it work in ASP.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently working with `flexbox` as you have a form element too nested in.

So try this- apply flex to the form and also add this:

```
form {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Check and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```css
/* -------------- start of flexbox code ---------------- */

html {
  height: 100%;
}
.alignCenter {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.site form {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.siteContent {
  flex: 1;
}
/* -------------- end of flexbox code ---------------- */

/* -------------- Not so relevant for the flexbox problem ---------------- */

form {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
  height: 20vh;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  font-size: 22px;
}
/* footer */

footer {
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body class="site">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <header>

      <nav class="alignCenter">
        <!-- for vertical and horizontal alignment -->

        <ul>
          <li><a href="Default.aspx" title="">Forside</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="portfolio.aspx" title="">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="kontakt.aspx" title="">Kontakt</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="siteContent">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
      </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </main>

    <footer>
      <p>Some footer text</p>
    </footer>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: It does, thank you very much :)

Could you help me understand why it works, i don't get why positioning the form has anything to say.

Comment: that is because `flex` works on the direct child divs and positioning is necessary to strectch the `form` element to fill the body

Comment: So by adding the five lines of CSS for the form it is told to fill up the whole screen?

Comment: yes, it fills up the `body` element- you can see that by inspecting element in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

If you want the footer always at the bottom. You need to declare position fixed and bottom: 0. I don't think you can achieve it by using flexbox only.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8eep942d/5/